# How to clear these intervals?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, intervals, clearinterval

I'm creating my own JSFiddle-like webapp and I want to implement elements resizing, but keep document height unchanged, so I have to recalculate elements dimensions on each resize.
I have this script:

```
var a = setInterval(setHeight, 1);
var b = setInterval(formsWidth, 1);
iframe.onResizeStart = a;
html.onResizeStart = b;
iframe.onResizeStop = clearInterval(a);
html.onResizeStop = clearInterval(b);
```

Iframe is an element where user codes are rendered and HTML is one of my three textareas. I want this script to recalculate textareas heights on iframe resize and recalculate their widths on changing width of one of them.

I managed to make this work, but I couldn't stop intervals and I need help with it.
The above code doesn't work now at all, probably because of calling a variable onResizeStart.

I'd be grateful if someone could help me.
I prefer not to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're calling clearInterval() almost immediately after calling setInterval(), so the intervals are never getting a chance to execute.  You'll need to store away a and b and then call clearInterval() on them at a later time, after the resizing is all done.

EDIT: Looking at this more closely, just wrap each call to clearInterval() in a function.  That way clearInterval won't get executed immediately, but rather when the onResizeStop event is fired.

```
iframe.onResizeStop = function() { clearInterval(a); };
```

Comment: It seems to work, hovever - in Firefox, in Performance tab I can still see a lot of setInterval events :/

Comment: I only showed the code for one of the intervals.  If you wrap both clearIntervals, and if both of your events are firing properly, you should see the intervals stop.  Put a console.log() call in each event function just before the clearInterval() call and see if each function is getting called by your event as you expect.